# Requests respond with a status "200 ok" but my browser does not render the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, http, ubuntu, https

Ubuntu 20.04. I'm working with vscode and using it to connect through SSH to a Coder virtual machine where my Rails app is running.

Since last friday, requests made to `localhost` complete with a status `200` ok, but my browser  is not rendering the HTML response.

request headers:

[image]

request response:

[image]

rails app server logs:

[image]

I've tried pretty much anything, including:

- different browsers
- fresh Ubuntu install
- different PC (macOs)
- different wifi
- disabling firewall
- downgrading the Remote-SSH extension in vscode

My Windows PC seemed to still work fine rendering 100% of requests. That is, until (I think) my vscode settings synced. However, I tried erasing all vscode user settings (`.json` file) in all computers to no success.

I have other apps running in the same manner (vscode => ssh => Coder VM) with no problems at all.

Can't figure out what the common factor is in all the solutions I tried (and if it's in fact the vscode settings, why removing them isn't working). Could it be some vscode extension other than `Remote-SSH` ?

Any ideas of what could be happening?

EDIT: Rails exception pages when visiting unexisting endpoints (aka red error page) load up without issues. It's the endpoints that do exist that don't load.

Comment: Is there any DOM tree being built in the browser?